# PHPExcel feature question

Tags: php, phpexcel, spreadsheet

I want to know if [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) can:

1. Create Excel spreadsheets with embeded image. The image **must be compressed** (jpeg, png, gif...).
2. Create Excel spreadsheets for different Excel versions (2000, 2003, 2007...).

I'm pretty sure it can do this but I can't find it in the official docs.

Anyone familiar with this class can help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep. It works great for all of the above. If you download the latest version there are docs in the Documentation/PHPExcel developer documentation.doc

Section 4.4.38 pg 26 shows how to add a GD drawing to a sheet.

Section 6.2.2 pg31 shows how to export in Excel 2007 format. Subsequent pages show other excel versions, and there is a useful set of tips on getting the right headers etc to make the .xls downloadable.

PS let me know if you need sample code... will post it here.

Comment: Obviously the docs change over time, to add a drawing it is now at "4.6.36. Add a drawing to a worksheet"

Comment: +1 for pointing to documentation of file, usefull because of lack on online docs, and +1 to bumperbox for updateing the file ref